# Image not position not correct?

Tags: image, position, padding, border-image

In this code i am preparing a portfolio, now when i am placing an
image in my portfolio the image is not filling the border div and
going a side as you can see in the picture <[IMAGE-first half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V1Xq.png)> ,  <[IMAGE-second half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Hzf.png)>. Can someone help me to keep four images that has borders only to the image and I need all four images placed like four boxes?

```html
<section class="latestwork" id="work">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="heading">
        <h2 class="boxx">My Latest Work</h2>
        <h6>These are my latest mobile photography captures</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="myworkbuttons">
        <button type="button" class="myworklink" data-filter="all">All</button>
        <button type="button" class="myworklink" data-filter="creative">Creative</button>
        <button type="button" class="myworklink" data-filter="black&white">Black/white</button>
        <button type="button" class="myworklink" data-filter="portrait">Portraits</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="portfolio-items" data-category="urban-floods">
        <div class="portfolio-inner-item" style="">
          <div class="portfolio-img">
            <img src="C:\portfolio's\drive-download-20210208T164603Z-001\The Disaster of 2020.jpg" alt="Image not loading">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-info">
          <h4>Iso: </h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio-items" data-category="buffalo">
        <div class="portfolio-inner-item">
          <div class="portfolio-img">
            <img src="C:\portfolio's\drive-download-20210208T164603Z-001\buffalos path.jpg" style="float: left;" alt="Image not loading">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the size of the image is not big enough.

Try adding `width: 100%` of the image component.

Comment: i have already used the width: 100% in css

Comment: Ok first of all remove float which is an older approach and also check the inspect element there you can get what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can use grid and and use css importing file and try this code:  `.div{background-image: url("/assets/pics/picture.jpg"); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; min-height:50vh; min-width:50vw }//(or what size do you need.);`

Comment: can you please write a code of the grid layout with css to insert images equally with space b/w them

Comment: <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 leftside1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 rightside1"></div></div>
 <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 leftside2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 rightside2"></div></div>
</div>

the col-md-6 is the class of bootstrap and use grid system. this means the the leftside1 div is equal to rightside1 div. if you don't if you dont use bootrsap in css 
you must .container{ display: grid; grid-template-row: 1fr 1fr; grid templete-column:1fr 1fr } then:

Comment: .leftside1{grid-row: 1/2; grid-collumn: 1/2; url("/assets/pics/picture.jpg"); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; min-height:50vh; min-width:50vw border: 2 px solid black} 
for border you can set only left top , for the rightside1 you can set bordrer right and top. and for the other 2 you can put border up left down for leftsite and up right and down for rightside2 div.

if you use bootstrap you don't need to put in css display-grid. only select the clases for grid. col-md-6 you can change 6 is half of width, change with 12 is 100%